# MACROS - How to implement divide and then round

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What is the proper way to perform a divide and round to lower number for a macro?

I am trying to do this:

```
#define TOTAL_NUM_FFTS  (int) NO_SAMPLES / FFT_SIZE
```

but I am getting a warning of incompaitible redefinition of that macro and the compiler restates the line as:
 `#define TOTAL_NUM_FFTS(int) NO_SAMPLES / FFT_SIZE` without the space between TOTAL_NUM_FFTS and (int).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#define TOTAL_NUM_FFTS  ((int) (NO_SAMPLES) / (FFT_SIZE))
```

The preprocessor thinks (int) is a parameter to the macro.

When defining macros, use as many parentheses as you can. For example, think what will happen if someone defines FFT_SIZE as 2+3. Instead of dividing by 5, you'd be dividing by 2 and then adding 3.

Comment: I did this:#define TOTAL_NUM_FFTS ((int) NO_SAMPLES / FFT_SIZE) and I am still getting the same warning with the compiler saying incompatible redefinition  and spits out the line #define TOTAL_NUM_FFTS((int) NO_SAMPLES / FFT_SIZE) without the space between.  O_O

Comment: Darn.  Yes, I had one hiding in the c code and one in the header file.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @O_O: Do you use header guards?

Comment: No.  Sounds like it is recommended to use header guards.  I just looked it up and it is a #ifndef, #define, #endif.  Sounds really troublesome to do this for every header file I have.  I don't really know if it is worth the trouble if you have i.e. 8 header files.  What do you think?

Comment: @O_O: Putting header guards each time is a very good habbit. Comparing to size of an usual .h file, the overhead is tiny.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to check:

- always properly parenthesize your macros (and macro arguments), as [Ilya mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548494/macros-how-to-implement-divide-and-then-round/4548522#4548522)
- make sure there isn't a duplicate (or near duplicate) definition of the macro somewhere else.  The error message should tell you exactly where, but if it doesn't, grep or similar will help (maybe there's an older version of your header hiding in some other directory f the include path?).
- make sure your header file is protected against multiple inclusion with [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). I don't think this is what's happening to you since since identical macro redefinition is supposed to be accepted by a C or C++ compiler, but you should still make sure your header has this.

Answer (score 0):

For dividing, you can use the pow(base, exponent) function available in math.h library.
I suppose you have to implement something like,

```
#define C A/B    //B!=0
```

then instead of it use the following:

`#define C A*pow(B,-1)`